# el mismo codigo me da error

Tags: android

estoy intentando seguir los pasos de un ejemplo para crear un menú horizontal, y el mismo código a mi me muestra un error.

Este es el codigo del MainActivity

```js
package com.ejemplo.socu.menuhorizontal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenulibrary.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    HorizontalScrollMenuView menu;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        //Create menu
        initMenu();
    }

    private void initMenu() {
        menu.addItem("Transaction",R.drawable.ic_money);
        menu.addItem("Payment",R.drawable.ic_payment);
        menu.addItem("Account",R.drawable.ic_acc);
        menu.addItem("Support",R.drawable.ic_done);

        menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+menuItem.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(menuItem.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Y me esta marcando el siguiente texto con error, y es el mismo que hay en el ejemplo para crear el menu:
menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new **HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener**(){

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Un saludo.

Comment: Y cual es el error que te marca

Comment: Hola @David, lo que he marcado en negrita, se queda con una marca roja, y lo getText() tambien.  
 
Mira la imagen

http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1712/5d/3b3144e5aeb7.png

Comment: Ubica el puntero encima de la frase en roja y aprieta Ctrl+Enter

Comment: Hola eyllanesc ya lo hice, con Ctrl+Enter no hace nada, me parte la linea, pulse Alt+Enter, pero me cambia el código y ya no es el mismo que el del ejemplo, el codigo lo dejo como en la siguiente imagen, pero luego cuando lo paso al emulador no funciona, muestra el mensaje que tambien pongo en esta imagen http://s41.radikal.ru/i091/1712/bf/5ee765fb03a1.png, de todas formas ese codigo quiero cambiarlo, en su lugar quiero que me muestra una pagina web cuando es escoge una opción del menu.

Comment: Quieres hacer un navigation drawer ?

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo conseguido, bueno lo estoy probando y parece que funciona, pero no estoy muy puesto en programación y me quedo con un poco de preocupación por si luego falla algo. Me pasaron un proyecto incompleto con dos menús diferentes, uno para que cuando el móvil en vertical muestre ese menú, y en horizontal muestre otro diferente, no conseguía hacerme con él, así que he empezado un proyecto nuevo que gracias he lo encontrado aquí https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5508  como el funcionamiento es diferente al que yo quiero darle, pues empezaron los problemas, jeje.

Comment: gracias a que puedo contar con vuestra ayuda. Una cosa que falla es que intento poner en el menú un icono/botón para que al pulsarlo vuelva hacia atrás, porque ahora si pulso el botón físico la aplicación sale, me podéis ayudar con ésto ?

Comment: @SoCu agregué una respuesta, en realidad el problema es el import de la clase MenuItem; cambia tu import: import android.view.MenuItem; realiza el import de la clase MenuItem de la library, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no estas implementado el metodo `OnHSMClick` porque estas utilizando el metodo `onHSMClick`. Reemplaza la primera o por una O mayuzcula:

```
  menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener(){


            @Override
            // la O debe de ser mayuscula
            public void OnHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+menuItem.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(menuItem.getText());
            }
        });
```

Comment: si la cambio por una mayúscula me muestra el error, o que queda la marcada en rojo, si le pongo en minúscula no muestra ese error o advertencia.                                      .
Aprovecho para preguntaros porque estando el móvil en posición vertical mostrando una página, si pongo el móvil en horizontal se cierra la página, como puedo hacer para que la página se sigua quedando cuando se cambia de posición el móvil.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso me parece que estas usando una librería : [HorizontalScrollMenu](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5508) ; el error refiere a que falta la implementación del método `onHSMClick()`, pero en realidad los estas realizando correctamente:

```
    menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {

                ....
                ....
        }
    });
```

Si en realidad estas realizando correctamente la implementación, ¿Cual sería el problema?, 
bien pues **el problema es que la clase `menuItem` no tiene el método `getText()`**:

```
menuItem.getText()
```

Pero si damos un vistazo a [la library, esta contiene un método publico para obtener el texto](https://github.com/MorochoRochaDarwin/HorizontalScrollMenu/blob/master/horizontalscrollmenulibrary/src/main/java/com/darwindeveloper/horizontalscrollmenulibrary/extras/MenuItem.java),

```
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

**Por lo tanto el problema es que no estas usando la clase correcta `MenuItem`, la clase debe ser la de la library,** no uses la del sdk que es:

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: ¿Me pregunto  porque -1?, puedo asegurar que la información es correcta. =0

Comment: Mañana volver a repasar vuestros comentarios y el código, porque ya no sé por dónde me ando, el cogido lo he cambiado para que no muestre el texto que sale al pulsar un menú, lo he cambiado para que me muestre una página web. Jorgesys no sé porque sale -1, te puedo asegurar que yo no lo he puesto, todo lo contrario, estoy muy agradecido por vuestros comentarios, le doy para ponerlo en positivo como respuesta útil, pero no hace nada, solo sale un texto dando las gracias. Me podéis decir como pongo el código aquí para que lo reviséis ?, y como poner líneas para que no salga el texto seguido?

Comment: Bueno el error original de la pregunta se debe a que usas una clase MenuItem no adecuada, debe ser la de la library : import com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenulibrary.extras.MenuItem; Para revisar si deseas sube tu código a https://github.com/

Comment: Ok, mañana lo preparo y si no te importa lo subo a otra pagina para que lo descargues como Google Drive, en otro post te pedí el correo para enviarte el link por correo por correo para que lo descargaras, porque entendí que pedías que colorar todo el código, y como aquí te deja escribir lo justo, no podía.

Comment: Link del proyecto https://goo.gl/HTAAhJ se produce un error al volver con el botón físico, como puedo poner un botón en el menú para ir hacia atrás?  y cuando está mostrando una página en posición vertical, al ponerlo en horizontal se cierra el menú. Hay que poner de forma independiente las opciones del menú, lo digo para que no cambien el contenido que estemos viendo al pasar a otro menú, y luego volver a los menús anteriores.

Comment: También hay un apartado Teléfonos que al pulsar sobre uno no muestra el teclado para hacer la llamada, si se hace desde la página web, si funciona, al poner la página en Android Studio no funciona.
Una cosa más, a este tipo de menús se le puede poner un submenú, y a este submenú otro submenú mas?

Comment: En ninguna parte de tu código veo lo que originalmente agregas a tu pregunta. Además veo que ya usas el import que no es del SDK lo cual resuelve el problema de la pregunta. Ya funciona menuItem.getText().

Comment: Ok gracias, no entiendo muy bien tu comentario sobre el código, lo fui cambiando conforme iba probando por eso puede que no sea el mismo que he subido, entiendo que todo está correcto, aunque me sigo encontrando con los problemas que he comentado más arriba, no sé si son normales o se pueden solucionar/cambiar, los preguntare en un nuevo post, y como dices que uso el import que no es del SDK podre tener alguna limitación. Por cierto, sigo sin poder puntuarte no veo ninguna opción para hacerlo.